# show image on link click and hide it when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show images on a link click and hiding that image if clicked outside. After trying so many solutions for this I have came up with like below code.

```
<script>
    function setImageVisible(id, visible) {
        var img = document.getElementById(id);
        img.style.visibility = (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    }
</script>
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: -5px; text-align:center" align="center" onclick="javascript:setImageVisible('popup1', false)">
    <a href="javascript:setImageVisible('popup1', true)"><div id="Btn7"></div></a>
    <img id="popup1" class="img_popup1" src="../screenshots/pop-up.png" style="visibility:hidden" />
</div>
```

The above code is working fine. But when I add other image like below, its not working. When I clicked outside then images are not hiding.

```
<script>
    function setImageVisible(id, visible) {
        var img = document.getElementById(id);
        img.style.visibility = (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    }
    $(document).click(function() {
        var img1 = document.getElementById('popup1');
        var img2 = document.getElementById('popup2');
        img1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
</script>
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: -5px; text-align:center" align="center">

    <a href="javascript:setImageVisible('popup1', true)"><div id="Btn7"></div></a>
    <img id="popup1" class="img_popup1" src="../screenshots/pop-up.png" style="visibility:hidden" />
    <a href="javascript:setImageVisible('popup2', true)"><div id="Btn8"></div></a>
    <img id="popup2" class="img_popup2" src="../screenshots/pop-up2.png" style="visibility:hidden" />

</div>
```

Can anyone please suggest what should I do ?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Are you getting any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: @ Øle Bjarnstroem: yes. js errors like `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and `The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`

Comment: @ Øle Bjarnstroem: but when I put `setImageVisible` function inside ` $(document).click(function() {` it shows nothing on link click.

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: @kiran There are two people who have answered. Did you try with them, and did you include the jQuery library?

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar: I am trying the answers.

Comment: @ Arcanyx, @  Praveen Kumar: I have not used any external jquery for above but have in my html for my other functions.

Comment: @kiran Ok, where to start: Always check your console for errors before posting here. When you get `$ is not defined` then you obviously didn't include the jQuery library but try to use it when calling '$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do this.

```js
function setImageVisible(id, visible) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.visibility = (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
}

function hideAll() {
    var img1 = document.getElementById('popup1');
    var img2 = document.getElementById('popup2');
    img1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function click(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var id, el = this;

    while (el) {
        el = el.nextSibling;
        if (el.nodeName === 'IMG') { // finds the next sibling img element
            id = el.id;
            el = null;
        }
    }

    hideAll(); // hide all images
    setImageVisible(id, true); // show the right one
};

document.addEventListener('click', hideAll);

var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'),
    i = 0,
    len = btns.length;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', click);
}
```

```css
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: -5px; text-align:center" align="center">
    <div class="btn" id="Btn7">Image 1</div>
    <img id="popup1" class="img_popup1" src="../screenshots/pop-up.png" style="visibility:hidden" />
    <div class="btn" id="Btn8">Image 2</div>
    <img id="popup2" class="img_popup2" src="../screenshots/pop-up2.png" style="visibility:hidden" />
</div>
```

Comment: @ TheGr8_Nik: Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me what is that `while` loop which is used for finding the next sibling in your code?

Comment: @kiran is because you are not sure if the next siblings element will be the img element or the "invisible" text element. You can add a console.log before the if statement and you will se what appens

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline event handler and write for common click event ,

1) bind the click event for all a tag inside wrapper id and then show the images when link is clicked

2) bind the click event for document and hide the all images when clicking outside of link

```
$("#popup1,#popup2").hide();
$("#Btn7,#Btn8").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next().show();
})
$(document).click(function () {
    $("#popup1,#popup2").hide();
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j1ksrdcp/5/)**

Comment: Did you checked demo link or anything u need

Comment: @ Bala: By applying the code which is in the DEMO, the two images are displaying on load only not on click.

Comment: yes, but I have no text like Link1 and Link2 and I have other images also in my `wrapper` div. I could not able to figure out what is affecting.

Comment: ok ... how to click link without text ,you only need 2 images popup1,popup2 ?

Comment: he can show something like button using css. No text compulsory.

Comment: @Newinjava  ok what ever wish,that is not problem here,

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as you have added a tag [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I am asking you to do it in a simple way like this:

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".imgPreview").hide();
  $(".unstyled li a").click(function () {
    $(".imgPreview").show().find("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
  });
  $("body").click(function () {
    $(".imgPreview").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
body {margin: 10px;}
li {margin: 5px;}
.unstyled, .imgPreview {float: left; width: 50%;}
.unstyled, .imgPreview img {max-width: 100%;}
p {margin: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on a link to show the respective image. Click outside to hide it!</p>
<p>Also you can right click and open it to open the image in a new tab!</p>
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150">350x150</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/750x150">750x150</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150">350x150</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/100x100">100x100</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150">350x150</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="imgPreview">
  <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar: Can you please tell me how do I apply above code with my code?

Comment: @kiran Just replace the full `<div>` contents with just the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="imageLink">Click to show image</a>
    <img id="image" style="display:none;height:500px; width:500px;">   
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#imageLink').click(function (e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('#image').show();

        });

        $('body').click(function () {
            $('#image').hide();
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#linkbutton_id").click(function () {
            alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
            if($("#image").hide())
            {
                $("#image").show();
                 return false;
            }

        });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#div_id").click(function(){

    $("#image").hide();
    });
});
```

Code plus output link
https://jsfiddle.net/umxrn0Lg/2/

fullscreen output link
https://jsfiddle.net/umxrn0Lg/3/embedded/result/